# How to calculate gain of wheatstone bridge+differential amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, differential, wheatstone-bridge

Can someone help me solve this task?

The schematic shows that the sensors are connected in series parallel and that the measurement is done using a Wheatstone-Bridge and a difference amplifier.

[image: Wheatstone Bridge]

**A)** Create a Wheatstone bridge by Circuitlab or by hand and balance it with a resistor of 330 Ohm and a voltage source (DC) of 5V for 23 degrees! Write down calculations.

**B)** Use Op-Amp AD8615 and create a differential amplifier that provides (near) 0V at the output for 23 degrees and (near) 5V for 100 degrees.

Comment: Is this of educational source (school, study). Are you sure you want 330Ohms, not 320?

Comment: @sgt_johnny, yes it is! It says 330Ohms

Comment: Hi @Andyaka, I writed the task as it is in the resource!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free design house, homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your work and findings so far in considerable detail with any schematic. The schematic tool here is easy to use. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a very warm welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A) Create a Wheatstone bridge by Circuitlab or by hand and balance it with a resistor of 330 Ohm and a voltage source (DC) of 5V for 23 degrees! Write down calculations.

Providing a complete solution for a study or school project, does not use anything in learning the specific topic, that's why I will just provide a explanation of the resistor circuit. The rest about the Differential Amplifier can be found on many internet resources.

I've recreated the shown circuit to show the correct annotations.

[image]

*R0* is the resistor connected in Series with the RTD Resistor *Rsensor*. Given the formula for Rsensor:

Rsensor = R0 x (1+ a Delta T) translates to Rsensor = 330 Ohms *(1+0), which is 330 Ohms since temperature has not changed.

R0 and Rsensor build a *Voltage Divider*. By building the exact same voltage divider and connecting both middle points to a differential opamp, you have a differential readout because of:

**Vout 1 = (5V X Rsensor) / (R0 + Rsensor) =  (5V x 330) / (330 + 330)  = 2.5V**

same formula for the second divider:

**Vout 2 = (5V X R2) / (R1 + R2) =  (5V x 330) / (330 + 330)  = 2.5V**

The differential amplifier will output the amplification of the difference between the both input terminals which would be : **2.5V-2.5V = 0V**

When the temperature changes, Rsensor will change its value, for example become 470Ohm:

**Vout 1 = (5V X Rsensor) / (R0 + Rsensor) =  (5V x 470) / (330 + 470)  = 2.93V**

R1 and R2 would stay the same:

**Vout 2 = (5V X R2) / (R1 + R2) =  (5V x 330) / (330 + 330)  = 2.5V**

Which would result in the following difference: **2.93 - 2.5 = 0.43V**

Rsensor will change 0.33% for each Kelvin difference from 23°C. In terms of change 1Kelvin = 1 Celsius.

For example:
Temperature rises by 10 Kelvin  which would result in:

**Rsensor = 330Ohm x (1+ (0.0033 * 10)) = 340.89 Ohm**

Hopefully this will get you further with your task!